# or-tools: Convert a BoundIntegerExpression to an IntegerExpression

Tags: c#, or-tools, sat

I am using `Google.OrTools` version 7.0.

---

I have built a small interface in order to add constraints to a `CpModel`:

```
public interface ISatConstraintWrapper
{
    IEnumerable<BoundIntegerExpression> GenerateConstraints();
    void BindToModel(CpModel model);
}
```

The design pattern is fairly simple, here is a dummy example that sets equality to all `IntVar`s in a list:

```
class MakeAllVarsEqual : ISatConstraintWrapper
{
    public MakeAllVarsEqual(List<IntVar> vars)
    {
        _vars = vars;
    }

    public IEnumerable<BoundIntegerExpression> GenerateConstraints()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < _vars.Count - 1; i++)
        {                
            yield return _vars[i] == _vars[i+1];
        }
    }

    public void BindToModel(CpModel model)
    {
        foreach (var constraint in GenerateConstraints())
        {
            model.Add(constraint);
        }
    }

    private readonly List<IntVar> _vars;
}
```

---

Next, I would like to use my `ISatConstraintWrapper` but for minimize/maximize constraints.

Here is an example of what I aim to do:

```
class MinimizeIntExpression : ISatConstraintWrapper
{
    public MinimizeIntExpression(List<IntVar> vars, List<int> coeffs)
    {
        _vars = vars;
        _coeffs = coeffs;
    }

    public IEnumerable<BoundIntegerExpression> GenerateConstraints()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < _vars.Count; i++)
        {                
            yield return _vars[i]*_coeffs[i];
        }
    }

    public void BindToModel(CpModel model)
    {
        model.Minimize(new SumArray(GenerateConstraints()));
    }

    private readonly List<IntVar> _vars;
    private readonly List<int> _coeffs;
}
```

But I can't, since `_vars[i]*_coeffs[i]` returns an `IntegerExpression` but not a `BoundIntegerExpression`.

However, even if the latter represents an `IntegerExpression` in a domain, those two classes seems unrelated and I didn't find a way to downcast a `BoundIntegerExpression` to an `IntegerExpression`.

Of course I could make two different interfaces but it wouldn't come as handy, for instance if I want to store my constraint wrappers in a list.

---

**Is it possible to convert a `BoundIntegerExpression` to an `IntegerExpression`? If not, how could I modify my wrapper to handle both types of constraints?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

I suggest you read:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how channeling could help me. Do you suggest to half-reify all my hard constraints from `F_i(X) = a_i`  to `b_i == (F_i(X) = a)` and create a minimization objective weighted by the `b_i`s, in order to only have minimization constraints?

Comment: Let me backtrack, you want to express what with Minimize/Maximize ? Do you confuse the objective part (model.Maximize and model.Minimize) with the Min/Max constraints (model.AddMinEquality, model.AddMaxEquality) ?

Comment: Nope, I edited my question and added a concrete example of what I aim to do, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: You need to duplicate the API, one which returns constraints, one which returns expressions. You minimize an expression, not a constraint.